# Accessing template type instance members

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to understand how templates work. So far I read tons of literature on the subject, but I still have a lot of questions.

I don't understand why this code is not compiling:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct SimpleVertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float r, g, b, a;
};

struct TexturedVertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float u, v;
};

// Template class declaration
template<class T>
class Primitive
{
public:
    Primitive(const T& vertex)
    {
        cout << "Usual constructor" << endl;
    };

    ~Primitive();

};

// Template function
template<class T>
void printVertex (const T& vertex)
{
    cout << "Printing r, g, b, a" << endl;
    cout << vertex.r << " " << vertex.g << " " << vertex.b << " " << vertex.a;
}

int main()
{
    SimpleVertex simple;
    simple.r = 264;
    simple.g = 123;
    simple.b = 731;
    simple.a = 0;

    Primitive<SimpleVertex> prim(simple);
    //printVertex<SimpleVertex>(simple);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is from MSVS2012 IDE. When I call `Primitive<SimpleVertex> prim(simple)` line - it doesn't work and throws an error: `Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Primitive<struct SimpleVertex>::~Primitive<struct SimpleVertex>(void)" (??1?$Primitive@USimpleVertex@@@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main`, but when I call `printVertex<SimpleVertex>(simple)` instead - everything works fine.

So I don't know what is the difference between calling simple template function and calling templade class constructor?

Also I don't understand why can't I access SimpleVertex's members (r, g, b, a) inside Primitive's constructor, but can do that in separate template function just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to templates. You just need to provide a destructor for `Primitive`. The class has a declaration but no definition. You could add an empty destructor body:

```
~Primitive() {} // empty destructor
```

You would get the same kind of linker error with this non-template class:

```
struct Foo
{
  ~Foo();
};
```